# Oracle APEX 19.2 adding a filter to IG

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm trying to add a dynamic filter to IG. I have a column with date and I want to add a filter on date (today - 14days).

I don't wanna use WHERE clause becouse I need to give the user opportunity to change it with IG options.
So I'm trying to use a widget().interactiveGrid().

```
let today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate()-14);

apex.region("ig_report").widget().interactiveGrid(
    "addFilter",
    {
        type: 'column',
        columnType: 'column',
        columnName: 'DATE',
        operator: 'GT',
        value: today.toISOString().substr(0,10).replace(/-/g,'')
    }
)
```

and this working quite fine. When I load page it's adding this filter to report. Buut unfortunettly it's not displaying date on filter

[image]

but when you click on this filter you can see that there is Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API is not documented and thus shouldn't be used. Assuming you want to use it anyway, you need to add the time portion to the date string as zeros.

Try this:

```
let today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate()-14);

apex.region("ig_report").widget().interactiveGrid(
    "addFilter",
    {
        type: 'column',
        columnType: 'column',
        columnName: 'DATE',
        operator: 'GT',
        value: today.toISOString().substr(0,10).replace(/-/g,'') + '000000'
    }
)
```

Comment: Thx you Dan, I found that filter have format YYYYMMDD000000 thx to dev tool and it works.
I know it's not documented, but I couldn't other right possibility to set dynamic filter on IG. Is there any that can set a filter like this? I don't want to place it in where becouse user must have a chance to erase this filter

Comment: There's no other way at the moment. You just have to be careful with undocumented APIs because you're taking on some additional risk in that the APIs can change without notice. Hopefully, those APIs will be documented and supported soon. :)

Comment: I hope that will be in 20.1. I knew the rule about using udocumented API, but like you said there's no other possibility. Thanks for help btw